# Symfony 4.0 share DB connection with PdoSessionHandler

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony4

In Symfony 3, it was possible to use the `PdoSessionHandler` to store sessions with the same db connection as doctrine used: [Symfony 3.4 Docs](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/doctrine/pdo_session_storage.html#sharing-your-database-connection-information)

In Symfony 4, there seams to still be the `PdoSessionHandler`, [Symfony 4.0 Docs](https://symfony.com/doc/4.0/doctrine/pdo_session_storage.html), but unfortunately there is no information on how to share the DB connection.

In my opinion a DB connection belongs in the `.env` file, that shouldn't be added to version control/public and not as suggested in the docs, just hard-coded (including the password!!!).

How do I reuse a DB connection to store sessions in the DB using Symfony 4.0

Edit: Meanwhile I unsuccessfully tried this:

```
// config/services.yaml
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\PdoSessionHandler:
    arguments:
        - '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
```

In my `.env` file I have something like this: `DATABASE_URL=mysql://dbuser:dbpass@dbhost:dbport/dbsheme?charset=UTF-8` where of course `dbuser`, `dbpass`, `dbhost`, `dbport` and `dbsheme` are set to the params for the mysql connection

Unfortunately this gives me a `FatalErrorException` with the message: "Error: session_start(): Failed to initialize storage module: user (path: /var/lib/php/sessions)" what kind of bugs me is, that it tries to do something locally, when I want it to connect to a remote db.

Comment: Since you just want to share a connection (which is generally not a good idea) why not do what your link suggests and uncomment the !service line?

Comment: Could you elaborate why it's not a good idea to reuse the same connection?

Comment: Because your generally transient session data end up in your production database.  Session data (IMNSHO) should be tucked away in it's own dedicated database.

Comment: Makes sense, currently we just have a cron cleaning out old session data. If it was up to me, I'd store sessions on a Memcache or similar server.

Comment: Btw. Would you mind making an answer out of your comment I actually just looked at the "Configuring the Table and Column Names
" although there was the needed code in docs.

Comment: Just go ahead and add your own answer.  Never enjoyed getting credit for "read the docs" type answers.  And yes there are plenty of alternatives for session storage which make more sense (to me at least) to use when the file system is not appropriate.